# How to Embed a PDF Document in an Email Message

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook, ms-word

I am trying embed PDF into body of my email .

I tried following code but it keeps opening word but attaches `pdf` file but does not embed `pdf` as a object in the body of email. Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
Public Sub CreateNewMessage()
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 With objMsg
  .To = "test@tst.com"
  .Subject = "This is the subject"
  .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .Attachments.Add ("C:\Work\Dashbaord.pdf"), olOLE  'Attach PDF File
  'Embed PDF
         Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
            wordapp.Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Work\" & "Dashbaord.pdf"
            wordapp.Visible = True



        'Embed PDF
        wordapp.Visible = True
        Set wordapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        wordapp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="AcroExch.Document.11", _
        FileName:="C:\Work\Dashbaord & ".pdf", LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False

  .Display
End With

Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Should be something like this.*

```
Public Sub InsetObject()
    Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection
    Dim Email As Outlook.mailitem

    Set Email = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With Email
        .To = "0m3r@Email.com"
        .subject = "This is the subject"
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Temp\TempFile.pdf")
        .Display

         Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
         Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor
         Set Selection = wdDoc.Application.Selection

         Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="AcroExch.Document.DC", _
                   FileName:="C:\Temp\TempFile.pdf", _
                   LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

    End With

    Set Inspector = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set Selection = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

> [image]

---

> ***[InlineShapes.AddOLEObject Method (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/inlineshapes-addoleobject-method-word)***
>
> <sub>*Creates an OLE object. Returns the **[InlineShape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/inlineshape-object-word)** object that represents the new OLE object.*</sub>
>
> ---
>
> ***[InlineShape Object (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/inlineshape-object-word)***
>
> <sub>*Represents an object in the text layer of a document. An inline shape can only be a picture, an OLE object, or an ActiveX control. The InlineShape object is a member of the InlineShapes collection. The InlineShapes collection contains all the shapes that appear inline in a document, range, or selection.
>   InlineShape objects are treated like characters and are positioned as characters within a line of text.*</sub>
>
> ---

***Reference to Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library***