# VBA macro to embed OLEobject into an Outlook Appointment series

Tags: vba, outlook

We use Outlook calendar to keep track of room bookings at our local community centre. For each calendar appointment/room booking we insert an object from file (an excel spreadsheet). The spreadsheet and file path is the same for each booking. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwQJI.jpg)

[image]

I'd like to simplify embedding this spreadsheet with a macro. Unfortunately Outlook doesn't allow me to record one, so I'm trying to get to grips with scripting it with VBA. I tried recorded the macro in Word to see if it would copy over to Outlook (it doesn't - object variable not set). The code generated by Word was

```
Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:= _
    "Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12", FileName:= _
    "K:\OutlookCalendar.xlsm" _
    , LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

I think I need to specify DIMs, but I'm getting out of my depth and I've been unable to find a Google solution so far. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: See example https://stackoverflow.com/a/44599739/4539709

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First set a reference to the "Microsoft Word x.0 Object Library" so Outlook can recognize the objects used by Word - **`Click Tools/References`***

*Now In order to use your recorded macro in Outlook, you need to set a variable to the Selection object Item.*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub UseWord()
  Dim Inspector  As Outlook.Inspector
  Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
  Dim Selection As Word.Selection

  Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
  Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor
  Set Selection = wdDoc.Application.Selection

  '-> And insert your recorded macro here

End Sub
```

---

> ***IDE Tools / References***
>
> [image]

Comment: Superb, thank you - it works well. The first step of setting the reference nearly threw me - I spent longer than I care to admit trying to click Tools/Reference on your post! (for those like me - click Tools>Reference in the VBA window, and ensure Microsoft Word x.0 Object Library is selected)