# Put contents of OLEObject from Excel Workbook into body of Outlook email using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

The OLEObject is a Microsoft Word document object. I want the content of the file as text in the body. The Word document also contains an image.

I have a problem with the line of code to do this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Genera_email()
    Dim App As Object
    Dim MailItem As Object
    Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailItem = App.CreateItem(0)
    With MailItem
        .BCC = Selection.Value
        .Subject = "Text object"
        .Body = Worksheets(2).OLEObjects(1) ' the problem line
        .Display
    End With
    Set MailItem = Nothing
    Set App = Nothing
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Value = "V"
    Selection.Offset(1, -1).Select
End Sub
```

I use Microsoft Office 2016.

What is the correct syntax of this line of code?

Comment: I guess you want the text of the Word document inside the body of the e-mail. Try using VBA to open the document, and then select the text and paste it in the body of the e-mail. Another option would be to [attach the word file to the e.mail](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+attach+file+to+email)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44599739/4539709

Comment: i don't want an attachments in the email, i want the content file as text in the body. The word document contain also an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!! :-D

```
Private Sub SendEmail()
    Dim Outlook, Word As Object
    Set Outlook = CreateOutlook()
    Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Word.Documents.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Body.docx", ReadOnly:=True).Content.Copy
    Sleep 0.01
    Do While Start And Selection.Value <> ""
        With Outlook.CreateItem(0)
            .To = Selection.Value
            .Subject = "Text subject"
            .GetInspector.WordEditor.Content.Paste
            .Display
            .Send
        End With
        If IsSent() Then Selection.Offset(0, 1) = "V" Else Selection.Offset(0, 1) = "X"
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Sleep 0.01
    Loop
    Word.Quit
    Set Outlook = Nothing
    Set Word = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be in the body the content, you must copy file in a temp folder and after open with new object, copy the content and paste in the body .
To save the OLEobject in a folder you can use code like this:

```
Worksheets(2).OLEObjects(1).Copy    
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(ActiveWorkbook.Path).Self.InvokeVerb "Paste"
```

Then create Microsoft Word document object and copy the content.

If you want to attach.

```
 Option Explicit
Sub Genera_email()
    Dim App As Object
    Dim MailItem As Object
    Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailItem = App.CreateItem(0)
    With MailItem
        .BCC = Selection.Value
        .Subject = "Text object"
        .Body = "Say Hello"
        .Attachments.Add Worksheets(2).OLEObjects(1)
        .Display
    End With
    Set MailItem = Nothing
    Set App = Nothing
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Value = "V"
    Selection.Offset(1, -1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I already have the Body.docx file
I have to paste the contents inside the body, not as an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Genera_email()
Dim strFile As String
Dim strbody As String
strFile = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Body.docx"
Dim objWordapp As Object, objWordDoc As Object
Set objWordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
objWordapp.Visible = True
Set objWordDoc = objWordapp.documents.Open(strFile)
strbody = objWordDoc.Content
objWordDoc.Close
objWordapp.Quit

Dim App As Object
    Dim MailItem As Object
    Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailItem = App.CreateItem(0)
    With MailItem
        .BCC = Selection.Value
        .Subject = "Text object"
        .body = strbody
        .Display
    End With
    Set MailItem = Nothing
    Set App = Nothing
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Value = "V"
    Selection.Offset(1, -1).Select


End Sub
```